# ContentChildren for all children

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating a list of components from Back End data. I'm creating a `ContentChild` object to get the reference of them but there is no data in it. I've also tried with `ViewChild` but I only get the first.

There are different solutions in there but none of them is working. For this reason, I think this happens because the children components are created after the class is created (I may be wrong).

This is what I've done so far:

**table.component.ts**

```
export class tableComponent {
  @ContentChildren('relation') relationElements: QueryList<RelationElement>;
}
  colapseColumn(){
    this.table.resetChildElements();
    console.log(this.relationElements);

  }
```

**table.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let entity of table.tableEntity">
    <tr class="listTable--bodyRow" >
        <td class="listTable--bodyElement"
            *ngFor="let element of entity.printableElements">
            <container-relation
                #relation
                [element]="element"
                (collapseColumn)="colapseColumn();">
            </container-relation>
       </td
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried with `ViewChildren`:

```
@ViewChildren('relation') relationElements: QueryList<any[]>;
```

When printing `relationElements` I'm getting the following result:

```
QueryList {_dirty: false, _results: Array(0), _emitter: EventEmitter
```

The expected result should allow me to do something like:

```
this.relationElements.map(re => re.extended = false);
```

Comment: You should use `@ViewChildren("relation")` instead of `@ContentChildren()`, as there is no `ng-content` in your template

Comment: I've done it but I'm only receiving the first element instead of all of them.

Comment: [no you didn't](https://plnkr.co/edit/j07n3JmVlA5AxyxTZICt?p=preview)...

Comment: I did. there is the result in the question

Comment: did you checked the link of the plunkr I sent you ? The fact is the queryList cannot be populated while there is no component yet. That's why you should use the `changes` property. once again: [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j07n3JmVlA5AxyxTZICt?p=preview).

Comment: Done! I didn't needed to check the changes. I've used "@ViewChildren('relation') relationElements: QueryList<RelationElement>;" without the [] for the type. Also, I need to map the result to get it. Thanks @n00dl3!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `Observable` `changes` property on `QueryList` class, you can subscribe to it to get notified when a component is added or removed. You should also use `@ViewChildren()` instead of `@ContentChildren()` as there is apparently no `ng-content` in your template.

```
@ViewChildren('relation')
relationElements: QueryList<RelationElement>;

ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.relationElements.changes
    .startWith(this.relationElements).subscribe(()=>{
      console.log(this.relationElements);
      // do stuff when list updates
    });
}
```

[Working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/j07n3JmVlA5AxyxTZICt?p=preview)

Comment: The problem is that there is nothing in this.relationalElements. I have other ways to check the changes.

Comment: If you are not interested in component list changes, what is your question ? Because "Is there a way to force relationElements to be equal to ALL the container-relation component?" is greek to me...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the question to make it easier to understand.